# Tool to get a list of WCF Service Operations at an endpoint

Tags: wcf, documentation, soa

Is there a documentation tool for a WCF endpoint out there?

We are trying to setup governance of our WCF Services and it would be really nice to auto document the list of service operations on a given endpoint.

For example:  http://MyService:8080/Client.svc has the SaveClient, UpdateClient, GetClientById etc.  If I was auto generating documents then when a DeleteClient service gets added it is really easy to flag that for my SOA Governance Board to look at.

I know I could write my own using the code generation tools provided by Microsoft, but I was hoping that someone else already got this idea and coded it up for me.

(Basically I am looking for a WSDL to MS Word tool.)

Comment: What if you are using a binding that doesn't expose any metadata? For example REST? How can an automated tool possibly know that there is a `DeleteClient` method? Well, it can't. That would be feasible if you are using protocols that expose metadata such as SOAP for example.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov - I guess I should have clarified.  I am using WCF Services and WCF Data Services (OData).  Both of these are very discoverable if you know the endpoint address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just need to google a bit differently.

[Generating HTML documentation from WSDL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686103/generating-html-documentation-from-wsdl)

That question pointed me to WSDL Viewer, which seems to do what I need.