# Discover SOAP Params?

Tags: php

Is it possible to discover the input parameters for a SOAP web service?

Currently I'm var_dump'ing the result and getting the array structure of the result but everything is blank because I'm not passing the correct params. Is there a SOAP function that can tell me the input parameters?

I should mention, this web service didn't come with documentation. I know obviously documentation would be the first place to look but I have none. :)

Comment: Look at the WSDL that came with the web service.  It might be hard to read at first but it's just XML :)  Also there are tools that can build documentation off of this like like some found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1471077/16959

Comment: This will certainly help http://www.soapui.org/